# Problema con un iframe y bootstrap 4

Tags: google-maps, bootstrap-4

tengo una página de contacto donde coloco la parte del formulario de contacto en una mitad de la pantalla y mi intención es colocar en la otra mitad de la pantalla el mapa de la ubicación de la empresa.
Ahora bien, para ello hago lo siguiente:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
        ... formulario de contacto
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=xxxxx" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
   </div>
```

El problema que tengo es que tuve que poner un mapa de google maps creado como myMaps y la forma de compartirlo es a traves de un iframe de acuerdo al código que comparte google maps.
El problema que tengo es que el mapa no se reubica cuando achico la ventana, menos si lo tengo en otro tipo de dispositivo...
Alguien tiene una forma para poder corregirlo ?
Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al iframe puedes darle una anchura de 100% a través de estilos, pero antes debes quitar el atributo de width de tu iframe.
Como se muestra a continuación:

```css
iframe{
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
          ... formulario de contacto
     </div>

     <div class="col-md-6 embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
          <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=xxxxx" height="480"></iframe>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Pero ahí si es responsive ? Porque el problema que tengo es que no baja por debajo del formulario cuando se achica la web

Comment: debes agregar una clase mas a los envoltorios de tu formulario y de tu iframe, la cual deber ser .col-xs-12

Comment: Funcionó perfecto Alex !!! Un millón de gracias !!!